# Why are the images not coming up for document.createElement

Tags: javascript, dom

I am a very novice coder and I am creating a game that calculates the area of a given rectangle however once the page loads, the image does not show and thus the user cannot answer the question.

An example image has been copied below

[image: example]

The "score" does not display either. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```js
var number1;
var number2;
var response;
var calcanswer;
var score = 0;
window.onload = areaquestion1;
myScore.text = "SCORE: " + score;

function areaquestion1() {
    var question = document.createElement("question");
    question.setAttribute("src", "Images/2*1.png");
    question.setAttribute("width", "304");
    question.setAttribute("height", "228");
    question.setAttribute("alt", "2*1");
    document.body.appendChild(question);
    var number1 = 2
    var number2 = 1
    calcanswer = (number1*number2);
    var question = document.getElementById("question");
    question.innerHTML = "What is the area of this lego brick?";
    check();
    areaquestion2();
}

function areaquestion2() {
    var question = document.createElement("question");
    question.setAttribute("src", "Images/3*2.png");
    question.setAttribute("width", "304");
    question.setAttribute("height", "228");
    question.setAttribute("alt", "3*2");
    document.body.appendChild(question);
    var number1 = 3
    var number2 = 2
    calcanswer = (number1*number2);
    var question = document.getElementById("question");
    question.innerHTML = "What is the area of this lego brick?";
    check();
    areaquestion3();
}

function check()
{
    var statusDiv = document.getElementById("status");
    response=document.getElementById("answer").value;

    if(response != calcanswer)
    statusDiv.innerHTML="Incorrect";
    else
    if (response==calcanswer)
    {
        statusDiv.innerHTML="Very good!";
        score ++;
        document.getElementById("score").textContent = score
        document.getElementById("answer").value = "";
        problem();
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Lego Area</title>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Play.css">
    <script src="JavaScript/Play.js"></script>
  </head>
<body onload="areaquestion1();">
  
  <div class="header">
    <h1>LEGO AREA</h1>
    <p>Calculating <b>area</b> with Emmet.</p>
    <div id="score" class="score" value="SCORE:"></div>
  </div>
    
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      
      <div class="side">
        <div id="question"></div>
        <div id ="prompt"></div>
        <input type="text" id="answer"/>
        
      </div>

      <div class="main">
        <input id="solve" type="button" value="CHECK!" onclick="check()" />
      </div>

    </div>
  </form>
  <div id="status"></div>
  <!-- Footer -->
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="practice"> <a href="Practice.html"><img src="Images/legoBlue2.png" id="practicebtn"  width="20%"></a></div>
    <div class="play"> <a href="Play.html"><img src="Images/legored2.png" id="playbtn" width="20%"></a></div>
  </div>

  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The first thing you can do is check for any errors in your browser console. As you can see in the snippet above, you have two undefined reference errors

Comment: Hi, at least in the code you copy in the question, the problem is that areaquestion3() is not defined (see your browser console to see that).

Answer (score 1):

This is my first question I'm attempting to answer -- so pretty big deal. Anyway...

A few things I noticed:

1. I got pretty confused reading the code seeing the `question` variable being used so much for different parts of the code. So I changed the `var question` to `var imageBlock` to make it more readable for me.
2. You were running the `areaquestion1()` function onload. Since the `check()` function was run as a part of the `areaquestion1()` function it was being run as well, in-turn displaying 'Incorrect' even before an answer was entered. I changed this to `document.getElementById("solve").check();` to ensure it runs only after the CHECK! button was clicked.
3. Finally getting to your actual question. It looks like you are trying to use `document.createElement` to create an image with an `id` of `question`, however based on [geeks for geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-an-image-element-dynamically-using-javascript/) and [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp) you use the `document.createElement` to create the `img` element. THEN you can set the id attribute to whatever you like. In this case, I switched it to `imageBlock.setAttribute("id", "madeUpImg");` to help with my readability.

So this is what I did, I think there are a lot of improvements you can make, but this works and it will give you a good start:

```
function areaquestion1() {
var imageBlock = document.createElement("IMG");
imageBlock.setAttribute("id", "madeUpImg");
imageBlock.setAttribute("src", "guWFE.png");
imageBlock.setAttribute("width", "304");
imageBlock.setAttribute("height", "228");
imageBlock.setAttribute("alt", "2*1");
document.body.appendChild(imageBlock); // this appends it to the bottom of the page
number1 = 2
number2 = 1
calcanswer = (number1*number2);
var question = document.getElementById("question");
question.innerHTML = "What is the area of this lego brick?";
document.getElementById("solve").check();
// areaquestion2(); }
```

All of this is edited to address your further questions:

1. For appending it in the appropriate spot: I haven't had time to jump back in my code, but this is what I'm thinking. Currently, when you read your code you have `document.body.appendChild(question);` This JavaScript is telling the computer to find the document, then find the body of that document, then run the appendChild function. So, basically it is saying - "computer, append the question variable to the body of the document". So, what's wrong with this? Well, you want to append it to a specific `div`! So, you're extremely close, but you're not grabbing the `question` `div`! You need to use code to tell the computer to find the question div, then append the image to that div. I'd do something like this:  `document.getElementById('question').appendChild(imageBlock)` this now means the code is grabbing onto the div that you want to append it to then, appending the `imageBlock` to that `div`.
2. I commented out that `areaquestion2` because I know you're going to run into more problems. 1. If you call the `areaquestion2`in the `areaquestion1` function it will run immediately when the website loads (you're calling the area question1 on load). I think this is going to make both images appear at the same time. Why? It is just being instructed to append another image to the question div. 2. You probably don't want both images appearing at the same time. So, you're going to need to find a way to replace the first image rather then trying to add another one.

That's about all I can help you with on this for now. I think that if you continue to work through this then refactor it, you're going to learn a ton. I think you should try to bring this to one function by assigning questions to variables, then passing those variables in as arguments to your function. If you haven't already, I'd highly recommend going through FreeCodeCamp's stuff lesson by lesson.

Hope this helped!!

Comment: Thanks so much! It's working now! But two questions:

Comment: The image is at the bottom of the page even though the html div is in between the question and the input.  And when I copy this code for areaquestion2 and call on the function of areaquestion2, the function areaquestion1 stays almost as if the function of areaquestion2 was not called on.